# Copying file names to a text file in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, scripting

I've currently got a PowerShell script that copies the file names in a directory to a text file. It excludes .info files from the copy. This is my code as it stands:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Test\" -Recurse -name -exclude '*.info' | out-file C:\Test.txt
```

I need to dump out a different text file for each individual file it copies the name of, with the name of the text file that of the name it copies.

I've done a lot of reading and still can't seem to find a resolution. How can I fix it?

Comment: Need some clarification. Do you want to put each filename from `C:\Test.txt` into individual text file? What should be the name of each text file?

Comment: I need to put each file name from C:\Test into an individual text file. In the text file I need the name of the file title copied, and the name of the text file should also be the name of the file title copied. Does that clarify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\Projects" -Recurse -exclude '*.info' | ForEach { [System.IO.File]::WriteAllText("C:\test\"+ $_.Name + ".txt", $_.FullName)}
```

Comment: You could do it the more Powershell looking way, and just do ... | Foreach-Object {New-Item -path ‘x’ -name ‘x’ -itemtype ‘file’ -value ‘x’